# MVVM Navigation | Buttons inside of View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation, eventaggregator

Hello stack overflow community,
I'm new to MVVM and have worked on a couple of tutorials to get some of the basics working (bindings, RelayCommand etc..).
A single window Application works so far pretty good, but now I need to add a Login and one or two other "views". I was not expecting this to be that painful.... :D

After working on a tutorial from ([Github](https://github.com/CSharpDesignPro/Page-Navigation-using-MVVM)), I could figure out, if I place a button/command from the MainWindow.xaml for example to /view/Home.xaml the command still fires, the CurrentView also updates but the MainWindow doesn't update/show? So.... I'm very confused on what is going on, hopefully someone has a logical explanation.

After looking into a couple more examples on stack overflow, I was reading about MVVM light and messaging, is this the way to make things work? If so, could someone please show a simple example. not sure if a simple example exists..

Thank you very much,
Anything is helpful

Alex

PS: I have updated my Navigation Test Repository [github.com](https://github.com/alexmayr85/Navigation) that shows exactly the issue.
Hope there is an easy solution to this :D

**UPDATE:**

I have updated my code and came to the conclusion that I need to use either MVVM-light messaging or Prism Event Aggregator.

I decided to give Prism Event Aggregator a shot and have "tried" to implement the Interface and added the aggregator inside of my constructor in both view models, but now my whole solution doesn't work anymore.
What am I doing wrong here?

**NavigationViewModel.cs**

```
public class NavigationViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public NavigationViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        LoginCommand = new RelayCommand(Login);
        PwResetCommand = new RelayCommand(PwReset);
        LogoutCommand = new RelayCommand(Logout);


        // Startup Page
        CurrentView = new LoginViewModel();

        //Prism Event Aggregator
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        eventAggregator
        .GetEvent<MyEvent>()
        .Publish(true);
    }

    public class MyEvent : PubSubEvent<bool>
    {  
    }
```

**WorkOrderViewModel.cs**

```
    public class WorkOrderViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public WorkOrderViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        // Prism Event Aggregator
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        eventAggregator
        .GetEvent<NavigationViewModel.MyEvent>()
        .Subscribe(OnIsSavedEvent);
    }

    public void OnIsSavedEvent(bool isSaved)
    {
        bool IsModified = !isSaved;
    }
}
```

**NavigationView.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class NavigationView : UserControl
{
    public NavigationView()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // <-- System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/SirRufo/so-77657479-PageNavigation

Comment: Thank you Sir Rufo for sharing this github solution. I have tried to make sense of it, but wasn't able to extract the required information to make my project work. I'm sure it is possible, but I'm not there yet... I will do some more digging and see if that code makes sense to me at a later point in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by implementing MS Toolkit Messages, it was way simpler as I thought it would be.